# Rails Passing code to execute in views via render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, view, erb, helper

I thought I could use a "view helper" to quickly generate some nice views with panels

Helper @ views/shared/_panel_builder.html.erb

```
<div class="panel panel-<%= pclass %>">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <%= heading %>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-body">
        <%= body %>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-footer">
        <%= footer %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where I want to use it @ views/somewhere

```
<%= render "/shared/panel_builder",
    pclass: "info",
    heading: "Administrateur",
    body: "#{link_to @etude.administrateur.name, @etude.administrateur}",
    footer: ""%>
```

It does work except for the body, where it renders a string `<a href="/administrateurs/5411e0bb5374611a7c000000">A name</a>`

I tried removing the `#{}` but then it won't compile

Could you think of a working way to achieve what I want do do ? Or is my idea just not good ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell Rails that HTML within the string is safe to render using `html_safe`:

```
<%= body.html_safe %>
```